# Python-Django : ImportError at / : No module named urls

Tags: django, python-2.7, pydev

I have created Djnago project in eclipse. Unfortunately, i am facing issue when i run the project

ImportError at /
No module named urls

Here Error Page
http://dpaste.com/1499981/

Eclipse Project http://i1008.photobucket.com/albums/af204/shoaibshah01/Untitled_zps84f95b4f.jpg

urls.py Content

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'TestApp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Could you show your urls.py content?

Comment: What do you mean by "running" the project? What command are you trying to use?

Comment: I am using eclipse, so i am using "Run as Django" option

Comment: What happens if you try `python manage.py runserver` from the command line? (in the directory with manage.py in it)

Comment: my guess is that's a pythonpath issue. Have to try to make the imports using ipython ? it's a tool that allows you to compute python code directly on a console. you'll see directly which import lines aren't correct

Answer (score 1):

Try converting `admin.site.urls` to string `url(r'^admin/', include('admin.site.urls'))`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because your `TestApp` is not referenced in `INSTALLED_APPS` so Django have no idea it should process it.

Comment: `TestApp` isn't an app. it's the project

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **ROOT_URLCONF** to 'urls' value in **settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided for the error log is giving 404.

Perhaps you can try with the below code for admin in URLs.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Everything is looking correct in settings.py.

If the above changes are not working, please share error page again.